# Permission denied when downloading with transmission daemon

Tags: permissions, transmission

I installed Xubuntu and transmission daemon, set the download path to my home/user/TV shows, and get a permission denied when trying to download torrents through the transmission.

I tried `chmod -r 777` on this folder without success.

Please help!

Following is the output of `ps -ef | grep transmission`

```
chen@htpc:~$ ps -ef | grep transmission
109       1023     1  1 21:46 ?        00:00:35 /usr/bin/transmission-daemon --config-dir /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info

chen@htpc:~$ ps aux | grep transmission
109       1023  3.2  0.4  47684 16620 ?        Ssl  21:46   1:20     /usr/bin/transmission-daemon --config-dir /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info
chen      1852  0.0  0.0   4200   772 pts/0    S+   22:27   0:00 grep --color=auto transmission

enter code here
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `ps -ef | grep transmission` to the question. I don't think transmission-daemon has the right to write to home dirs by default.

Comment: I added it, how do I add permissions to this user ?

Comment: Well, I was after the name of the user it runs under, but it's not shown. Try `ps aux | grep transmission` instead.

Comment: Hm..., it looks like its username it 109 - kind of odd.

Comment: This is really bizarre, but it should be running under `debian-transmission`, not sure why it shows a stupid number. You can verify that with `id debian-transmission`.

Comment: This answer was also useful to me http://askubuntu.com/a/558074/11627

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Assuming the path to the download folder is `/home/chen/TV shows`, run the following:

- add chen to the debian-transmission group

  ```
  sudo usermod -a -G debian-transmission chen
  ```
- change the folder ownership

  ```
  sudo chgrp debian-transmission /home/chen/TV\ shows
  ```
- grant write access to the group

  ```
  sudo chmod 770 /home/chen/TV\ shows
  ```
- Stop the deamon with

  ```
  sudo service transmission-daemon stop
  ```
- The last thing to do is change the file creation mask, so that the downloaded files would be writeable by chen.

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json
  ```

  … and change `"umask": 18` to `"umask": 2`. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit.

Start the daemon with

```
sudo service transmission-daemon start
```

Comment: In case anyone tries to `cd` into their directory right after doing this and receive a permission denied, logout and login again. My SSH session did not have the right permissions to access the folder after folder ownership was given to `debian-tranmission` group (since my user wasn't added to that group until next logon)

Comment: This works up until I need to create a new folder (e.g. the torrent's files are nested).  Then I get another permission denied.

Comment: @GDorn That shouldn't be the case. `"umask": 2` translates to permissions of 774, or rwxrwxr--, which means fool access for owner and group.

Comment: Useful answer, but, maybe, I can suggest an editt to the answer: I had troubles with `/var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-demon/torrents`. This directory didn't have write permission. Changing them all stated to work.

Comment: @GDorn you can use chmod -R to make the command recursive

Comment: @matthew_360 running a chmod today, even with -R, won't affect a subdirectory I make tomorrow.

Comment: `sudo chmod 770 -R /home/chen/TV\ shows` is required to make it work

Comment: I did all of the above but it didn't work - however - I noticed on the default download dir it had the setuid set. So I tested this and added that to my new directory using `"chmod 4775 <mydir>"` and it is now working perfectly. I also added blocking lists for safe torrenting using the following.
`"/usr/bin/transmission-remote -n transmission:transmission --blocklist-update"` - this will use the blocking list you specified in the /etc/transmission/settings.json file.

Answer (score 9):

Check if you're using an "incomplete" folder.
The error can be misleading in this case and it may be the incomplete folder you do not have write access to.

Comment: that was my case: in the settings I had a wrong case for the incomplete dir.
So the error was doubly misleading: the error was not in the directory the error was telling and the error should have been "not found" and not "permission denied"

Comment: This was my problem! It had reset to /root/incomplete, which obviously isn't writable!

Comment: What @RiccardoCossu said. Can't upvote enough.

Comment: Same problem here. There was a folder called 'downloads' but settings.json was referring to 'Downloads'.

Answer (score 7):

This is a permission issue based on the user ID that is running Transmission. Transmission sets up a default user that you might not expect on first install. The user name is `debian-transmission`.

I will explain how to change that:

1. Stop the Transmission daemon `sudo service transmission-daemon stop`
2. Open the Transmission config file for editing: `sudo nano /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon`
3. Find the line that says `USER=debian-transmission` and change it to the user that owns the folder in question. If you are not concerned about security issues, you can also use `USER=root` in this file. (Not advised, but good for troubleshooting).
4. Alternatively (instead of point number 3), [modify the /etc/fstab folder to mount the folder with correct permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49371/fstab-folder-bind-on-partition-mounted-with-defaults-parameter) for the user that runs the transmission-daemon.
5. Start the Transmission daemon `sudo service transmission-daemon start`

Comment: That won't work. Here either the user `transmission-daemon`  or root also owns  "/var/lib/transmission-daemon/info/settings.json" and if you change the daemon to run as $USER , it will give `Couldn't read "/var/lib/transmission-daemon/info/settings.json": Permission denied`. It somehow worked in your system , But this is not the proper way to do it.

Comment: It works, thanks. And if your using ```systemd``` you should edit the ```User``` under ```[Service]``` at ```/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service```.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is the top search result in Google, for anyone reading this, I spend over an hour trying to get it to work. Turns out, the downloads folder specified in settings.json is "Downloads" instead of "downloads". Note the case.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an apparmor profile problem.  Transmission runs under the `sanitized_helper` profile in apparmor.

Look for complaints in /var/log/kern.log.  `grep transm /var/log/kern.log`, particularly just after trying to run transmission and it failing.

Answer (score 1):

This just happened to me.  I found this page, was intimidated by all the jargon, so I restarted Transmission, reserved the torrent file to a different location, and saved the torrent data to the same different location (desktop).  Worked like a charm...

Answer (score 1):

my problem was that transmission somehow was running as the user "transmissions-daemon" instead of the user it was supposed to run with.

Comment: How did you fix this? I have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was how the drive was being mounted. Using this in `/etc/fstab` worked for me:

```
UUID=2069-1A05  /mnt/ext   vfat   rw,user,exec,umask=0000   0   0
```

Comment: A bit of context might help here (`vfat`? Not a typical Linux filesystem) - what was your scenario, what exactly was not working and how did this fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Mounting the external drive into my home directory resolved this issue;

```
sudo mkdir /home/plex/media-server
sudo chmod 770 /home/plex/media-server
sudo mount /dev/sdxx/ /home/plex/media-drive
```

`sdxx` is the name of your hdd. you can use the following command to find yours:

```
lsblk
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the path for your incomplete torrents is absolute. My main directory was using `~/path-to-download`, which gave me an error. My incomplete directory was `~/path-to-download/incomplete`.

I received an error the first time I tried to download a torrent not using an absolute directory. I fixed that, but kept receiving a permission denied error, even after adding the correct permissions. Once I fixed my incomplete path to an absolute path, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo setfacl -m u:debian-transmission:rxw  /home/*your user*/*your path to folder*
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you edit this and add a little more explanation on what this command does and how to undo it if it does not work, it would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

None of these suggestions worked for me so I just set fstab to use transmission-daemon's default download directory as the mountpoint to mount my USB stick.

1. First I set the ownership of my USB stick to match that of the default download directory:

`sudo chown debian-transmission:debian-transmission /media/pi/[mountpoint]/`

2. Edit fstab:

`sudo nano /etc/fstab`

Insert the following text:

`UUID=[insert device UUID here] /var/lib/transmission-daemon/downloads    ext4    rw,user,exec 0 0`

Note: you can find your USB sticks UUID by running `sudo blkid`

3. Reboot the system:

`sudo reboot`

4. You can test whether it is writing data to your USB stick by running `df -ha` and checking whether the data written to your USB stick increases when you add a new torrent. Note that the data increase happens all at once when you add a new torrent and NOT gradually as the torrent downloads.

Answer (score 0):

I added the debian-transmission user to my $USER group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G <myusername> debian-transmission
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have the "download-dir", "incomplete-dir" (and "watch-dir") situated in my home-directory.

(presume my userid is '`[user]`')

`ls -la /home/[user]/Transmission` results in:

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 [user] debian-transmission 4096 sep 17 21:21 ./
drwxr-x--- 19 [user] [user]              4096 sep 20 20:08 ../
drwxrwxr-x  3 [user] debian-transmission 4096 sep 18 23:04 Completed/
drwxrwxr-x  4 [user] debian-transmission 4096 sep 20 20:11 Incomplete/
drwxrwxr-x  2 [user] debian-transmission 4096 sep 17 21:21 Torrents/
```

As you can see the user `debian-transmission` has all the necessary permissions to write in those directories except... it has no read and execute permission on `/home/[user]` !!! So as a result, `debian-transmission` cannot access its subdirectories either.

- *Lesson learned: check the permissions for the **entire path** ! Not just the final target directory !*

There are now 3 options (choose one !):

1. Add the group `[user]` to the user `debian-transmission` (`sudo usermod -a -G [user] debian-transmission`)
2. Set x-permissions on world for `/home/[user]` (`sudo chmod o+x /home/[user]`)
3. Stop the deamon, move the whole directory tree `/home/[user]/Transmission` to the home directory of `debian-transmission`. Set ownership of those directories to `debian-transmission:debian-transmission`. Edit `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json` likewise. Add group `debian-transmission` to `[user]` and -finally- start the deamon again.

Option 1 and 2 have some minor security issues so option 3 is probably the best.

Answer (score 0):

2022 and I had the same issue.

A simple `sudo chown debian-transmission:debian-transmission -R /path/to/download` solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

For those with custom locations, be sure you are applying chown to the original folder path and not a symlink.

```
sudo chown -R debian-transmission:debian-transmission /mnt/nas/downloads
```

NOT

```
sudo chown -R debian-transmission:debian-transmission /home/coolguy/nas/downloads
```

Add a 755

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /mnt/nas/downloads
```

I was able to get around the permissions issue by doing that. Also, no need to change the umask or 777 (or running as root, not a good plan).

Also, the latest transmission-daemon doesn't seem to include and error log. Add this to your config file if you need some error output for debugging:

```
"log-error-file": "/var/log/transmission-error.log"
```

Be sure to restart

```
systemctl restart transmission-daemon
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues, given my downloads folder is `/home/user/media`. After fixing the permissions of that particular folder so that the user `debian-transmission` could read and write (see accepted answer), it still did not work.

The reason was that my `/home/user` folder had incorrect permissions, to prevent other users from reading its content. To access a directory, a user must have execute permission on the parent folder. To fix that:

1. Either set to standard home folder permissions. All users will be able to read inside it now.

```
chmod 755 /home/user
```

2. Either add debian-transmission to your user group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G user debian-transmission
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable this setting, so no temprorary files should be save & cause permissions issue:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue, and that was a mistake I had made when sym-linking the transmission download directory to my home/user/ directory, I changed the ownership of the sym-linked file which by consequence also changed the ownership of the transmission 'download' directory...

I just chowned back to 'debian-transmission' ownership and it worked like a charm (without need to restart service)

```
#chown debian-transmission:debian-transmission /var/lib/transmission/downloads
```

(well, you'll have to check according your own linux distribution what is the right owner and eventually also your right path to the downloads directory)

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issue with transmission. I got Permission Error while downloading even with correct folder permission settings on the external USB HDD.

I just mounted the external HDD to the `/home/pi/` with the same permissions and it worked fine.

```
mount /dev/sda /home/pi/USB-HDD-MOUNTED
```

permissions are `drwxrwxrwx (0777) pi:debian-transmission`.
user name is changed to `pi` in `/etc/init.d/transmisssion-daemon`.