# Transmission not working on UUID disk and proper permissions

Tags: mount, permissions, raid, transmission

I cannot get any downloads finished, when it gets about 5mb downloaded, i get the Permission Denied error

transmission is running on debian-transmission

[This](https://askubuntu.com/a/221096/507623) answer does NOT work for me

Also, the disk i am writing on has read and write permissions for everyone, but the owner is set to the sudo user

Do not hesitate to ask if you need more info!

setting.json:

```
 {
"alt-speed-down": 50, 
"alt-speed-enabled": false, 
"alt-speed-time-begin": 540, 
"alt-speed-time-day": 127, 
"alt-speed-time-enabled": false, 
"alt-speed-time-end": 1020, 
"alt-speed-up": 50, 
"bind-address-ipv4": "0.0.0.0", 
"bind-address-ipv6": "::", 
"blocklist-enabled": false, 
"blocklist-url": "http://www.example.com/blocklist", 
"cache-size-mb": 4, 
"dht-enabled": true, 
"download-dir": "/mnt/raid1/downloads", 
"download-limit": 100, 
"download-limit-enabled": 0, 
"download-queue-enabled": true, 
"download-queue-size": 5, 
"encryption": 1, 
"idle-seeding-limit": 30, 
"idle-seeding-limit-enabled": false, 
"incomplete-dir": "/var/lib/transmission-daemon/Downloads", 
"incomplete-dir-enabled": false, 
"lpd-enabled": false, 
"max-peers-global": 200, 
"message-level": 1, 
"peer-congestion-algorithm": "", 
"peer-id-ttl-hours": 6, 
"peer-limit-global": 200, 
"peer-limit-per-torrent": 50, 
"peer-port": 51413, 
"peer-port-random-high": 65535, 
"peer-port-random-low": 49152, 
"peer-port-random-on-start": false, 
"peer-socket-tos": "default", 
"pex-enabled": true, 
"port-forwarding-enabled": false, 
"preallocation": 1, 
"prefetch-enabled": 1, 
"queue-stalled-enabled": true, 
"queue-stalled-minutes": 30, 
"ratio-limit": 2, 
"ratio-limit-enabled": false, 
"rename-partial-files": true, 
"rpc-authentication-required": true, 
"rpc-bind-address": "0.0.0.0", 
"rpc-enabled": true, 
"rpc-password": "", 
"rpc-port": 9091, 
"rpc-url": "/transmission/", 
"rpc-username": "diadras", 
"rpc-whitelist": "*", 
"rpc-whitelist-enabled": true, 
"scrape-paused-torrents-enabled": true, 
"script-torrent-done-enabled": false, 
"script-torrent-done-filename": "", 
"seed-queue-enabled": false, 
"seed-queue-size": 10, 
"speed-limit-down": 100, 
"speed-limit-down-enabled": false, 
"speed-limit-up": 100, 
"speed-limit-up-enabled": false, 
"start-added-torrents": true, 
"trash-original-torrent-files": false, 
"umask": 2, 
"upload-limit": 100, 
"upload-limit-enabled": 0, 
"upload-slots-per-torrent": 14, 
"utp-enabled": true
}
```

output of ls -l /mnt/raid1/:

```
diadras@Desktop:~$ ls -l /mnt/raid1/
total 52
drwxrwxr-x   2 diadras             diadras              4096 mei 13 16:21 Backup
drwxrwx---  10 debian-transmission debian-transmission  4096 mei 26 10:52 downloads
drwx------   2 root                root                16384 mrt  3 23:35 lost+found
-rw-------   1 diadras             diadras                82 mei 26 16:47 nohup.out
drwxrw-rw-   3 diadras             diadras              4096 mrt  4 16:43 owncloud2
drwxrw----.  3 diadras             diadras              4096 mrt  4 16:43 owncloudbackup
drwxrwxr-x   3 diadras             diadras              4096 mei 26 16:57 ShoppingBuddy
drwxrwxr-x.  2 diadras             diadras              4096 mrt  4 12:02 VM1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of messing with the config file, I prevented transmission-daemon from running automatically and opted, instead, to run it on demand.  I created a new user called "fetch", with no shell, and made him a member of the plugdev group.

Then, from my own shell, I execute...

```
sudo -H -u fetch bash -c "transmission-daemon"
```

The config file is, or course, located in `/home/fetch/.config`

Unless you have something weird going on with your file system permissions, substituting `debian-transmission` for `fetch` should work to allow the process to write to the necessary directories.

Good luck to you.

Comment: What do you mean with "plugdev" group?

Comment: Removable file systems (i.e, after the system has been installed) are owned by root:plugdev by default.  To add debian-transmission to that group, try `sudo usermod -a -G plugdev debian-transmission` and check with `groups debian-transmission`.

Comment: I just tried out your answer, but i still get permission denied.
I will be away this evening but retry when i get the time!
Thank you for your answer anyway :)

Comment: Actually, when you have time to come back to this, I just noticed your command output from where you listed the contents of `/mnt/raid1/`.  I wonder... could you back up one directory higher and tell us who owns the actual `raid1` mount point?  Just do a `ls -l /mnt`

Comment: Output of ls -l /mnt 
`drwxrw-rw- 10 diadras uucp 4096 mei 26 16:56 raid1`