# Transmission-daemon - Folder permissions issue

Tags: permissions, 22.04, transmission

Transmission-daemon can't write to a Downloads folder.

(I have installed and used transmission before, and i dont remember ever having trouble with it, i have read  these forums and i cant find an answer.)

Ubuntu 22.04, recently / fresh installation and Transmission-daemon. Any assistance with this will be greatly appreciated ! :) Thanks

To my understanding, this is saying the transmission-daemon is running as the user 'debian-transmission' ;

```
!
My_User@Store:~$ ps ax o user:20,pid,pcpu,pmem,vsz,rss,stat,start_time,time,cmd | grep trans
!
debian-transmission    52574  0.1  0.3 178152 11332 Ssl  Oct21 00:00:57 /usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error
!
```

Folder permissions show debian-transmission has rw permissions;

```
!
My_User@Store:~/Downloads$ ls -l
total 12
drwxrwx--- 2 debian-transmission debian-transmission 4096 Oct  9 13:08 Torrent_Files
drwxrwx--- 2 debian-transmission debian-transmission 4096 Oct 21 21:11 Torrents_Complete
drwxrwx--- 2 debian-transmission debian-transmission 4096 Oct  9 13:07 Torrents_Downloading
!
```

I'm not sure how relevant this is, but the init.d user for transmission-daemon is set as debian-transimission;

```
!
/init.d/transmission-daemon
!
NAME=transmission-daemon
DAEMON=/usr/bin/$NAME
USER=debian-transmission
STOP_TIMEOUT=30
!
```

syslog error when transmission tries to write to the folder;

```
!
/var/log/syslog
Oct 22 14:50:32 store transmission-daemon[52574]: [2022-10-22 14:50:32.351] Couldn't create "/home/My_User/Downloads/Torrents_Downloading/Mastering Ubuntu Server, 3rd Edition": Permission denied (file-posix.c:243)
Oct 22 14:50:32 store transmission-daemon[52574]: [2022-10-22 14:50:32.353] Couldn't create "/home/My_User/Downloads/Torrents_Downloading/Mastering Ubuntu Server, 3rd Edition": Permission denied (fdlimit.c:174)
Oct 22 14:50:32 store transmission-daemon[52574]: [2022-10-22 14:50:32.353] Mastering Ubuntu Server, 3rd Edition tr_fdFileCheckout failed for "/home/My_User/Downloads/Torrents_Downloading/Mastering Ubuntu Server, 3rd Edition/Mastering Ubuntu Server, 3rd Edition.epub.part": Permission denied (inout.c:95)
Oct 22 14:50:32 store transmission-daemon[52574]: [2022-10-22 14:50:32.353] Mastering Ubuntu Server, 3rd Edition Permission denied (/home/My_User/Downloads/Torrents_Complete/Mastering Ubuntu Server, 3rd Edition/Mastering Ubuntu Server, 3rd Edi (torrent.c:574)
Oct 22 14:50:32 store transmission-daemon[52574]: [2022-10-22 14:50:32.353] Couldn't create "/home/My_User/Downloads/Torrents_Downloading/Mastering Ubuntu Server, 3rd Edition": Permission denied (file-posix.c:243)
Oct 22 14:50:32 store transmission-daemon[52574]: [2022-10-22 14:50:32.353] Couldn't create "/home/My_User/Downloads/Torrents_Downloading/Mastering Ubuntu Server, 3rd Edition": Permission denied (fdlimit.c:174)
Oct 22 14:50:32 store transmission-daemon[52574]: [2022-10-22 14:50:32.353] Mastering Ubuntu Server, 3rd Edition tr_fdFileCheckout failed for "/home/My_User/Downloads/Torrents_Downloading/Mastering Ubuntu Server, 3rd Edition/Mastering Ubuntu Server, 3rd Edition.epub.part": Permission denied (inout.c:95)
!
```

Comment: Transmission and transmission-daemon are related, but not the same. So, which is it? Transmission-daemon should not have write permissions to an arbitrary Download folder by default. Use `ls -ld` to show folder permissions.

Comment: i guess in my case im using; transmission-daemon (i didnt realise there was a distinction between transmission and transmission-daemon). If i run that command, in the folder that transmission-daemon is trying to download to, this is the output; My_User@Store:~/Downloads/Torrents_Downloading$ pwd
/home/My_User/Downloads/Torrents_Downloading
!
!
My_User@Store:~/Downloads/Torrents_Downloading$ ls -ld
drwxrwx--- 2 debian-transmission debian-transmission 4096 Oct  9 13:07 .

Comment: Check this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221081/permission-denied-when-downloading-with-transmission-daemon/221096#221096

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever solved this, but I was just having the same issue (same error code at least) and found that while the specific folder I was trying to download the torrent to (./Torrents/Downloads) was owned by debian-transmission:debian-transmission, the parent folder (./Torrents) was owned by USERNAME:users.

I'm not sure why this was needed, but I found that changing the ownership of the parent folder to debian-transmission:debian-transmission resolved the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).